# Add value to return URL in PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I have a payment page which uses PayPal. It is working okay, but I would like to add a custom value to the return link after payment. For example

```
http://mypage.com/returnpaypal&email=eric@gmail.com
```

Is this possible in PayPal? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mypage.com/returnpaypal&email=eric@gmail.com">
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this data can be manipulated by the client side (buyer). So don't use it for any critical / sensitive data.